# Put all parts of my code in functions for an optimization model

Tags: python, function, optimization

I'm writing an optimization model and I would like to put parts of my code in functions to do something like this but I'm not sure on how doing it:

```
for file in files:
    data = extract_data(file)
    model = construct_model(data)
    model.solve()
```

As example, I'll copie/past the first 2 blocks of code in my program:

1st block:

```
from lxml import etree
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import*

url = urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ArthurK-GH/Instances/main/sprint01.xml')
doc = etree.parse(url)
root = doc.getroot()
```

2nd block:

```
getStart_date = root[0].text
getEnd_date = root[1].text

start_date = datetime.strptime(getStart_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.strptime(getEnd_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
delta = (end_date - start_date)

list_of_dates = []
for i in range(delta.days +1):
    day = start_date + timedelta(days=i)
    list_of_dates.append(day)


delta = (end_date - start_date).days +1
list_of_days = []
for x in range(delta):
    list_of_days.append(x+1)
    
zipbObj = zip(list_of_dates,list_of_days)
DicDatesDays = dict(zipbObj)
```

I don't want the first block to be in the function but you'll need it if you wanna run the code. Could you please guide me to find an efficient way to do it ? Thank you !

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What is supposed to be inefficient? The second block take less than 0.030 ms on my machine. This that not fast enough? As for the first it is hard to make it more efficient regarding what it does...

Comment: I don't understand what you say. First `I would like to put parts of my code in functions` and next `I don't want the first block to be in the function`. If you want only part of code in fucntion then put only part of code. Maybe first try to create function and when it will not work then come to Stackoverflow. `def extract_data(file): ....` and `def construct_model(data): ...` . Creating function is basic knowledge and it should be in any tutorial for basis of Python.

Comment: [Learn X in Y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python/) Where X=Python. Look for `4. Functions`